# Auto Populate DocuSign PowerForm

Tags: docusignapi

I'm wondering how i can populate the DocuSign Powerform. I studied on [Populating Custom Envelope Fields in a Web PowerForm](https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-powerforms/powerforms/populating-fields-web-powerform)
But I can't understand how to deal with the Envelope Field Name OR Secure Field Name.As far as i understand those are required to populate the form. But I'm wondering how can I add OR get those Envelope Field Name OR Secure Field Name. Please see the image for better understanding of what I'm trying to mean.
[image]

Regards
Efat

Comment: Good question. Secure Fields is a synonym for these yellow tabs you have added to the document. To find out their 'name', click on a tab, then on the right panel -> advanced -> data label. The value of data label (which i encourage you to make meaningful names) is what you will want to pass in the URL when you open your powerform (per the link you included above)

Comment: Great - glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

In the API the fields are referenced through the `tabLabel` property.  If editing manually through the DocuSign Console they are labeled as "*Data Label*" in the UI and can be accessed by selecting a tab and going to right panel -> advanced -> data label.