# DocuSign API - autofill fields and require signature

Tags: php, docusignapi

This is my first time trying to use the DocuSign API and I haven't been able to find an example of what I'm looking for.

What I'm trying to do is have a user fill out a form on a page, then push the data to DocuSign and use it to auto populate fields, so all they have to do is sign it. Is this possible?

I looked into Power Forms, but I don't seem to have that option when I go to edit the template. Plus, I already have an existing, functioning form I'd like to use.

Right now I'm just using the demo PHP code, which can be found here: [DocuSign demo code](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app)

Also, when I do use it, I'm not seeing the fields that I've added and the user is able to drag and drop any fields they'd like. The working example can ben seen here: [just add your email address to the `email` parameter](http://freeirsreport.com/docusign.php?email=youremailaddress@here.com)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it, one is through Powerform which needs that you create a template with the document and create all the datalabels of the document in which dynamic data will be populated using URL. Another way to do it through API, where using API you will send datalabel's values. You can see an example at https://loancosample.docusign.com/ how DocuSign works. Let us know what you have tried.

For populating Powerform, you can find details at
https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-powerforms-populating-fields-web-powerform or
[Auto Populate DocuSign PowerForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588573/auto-populate-docusign-powerform)

You can find many examples using API in stackoverflow